# [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, 17.10

I created a bootable USB for Ubuntu 17.10 (with Rufus), and when I boot on it, then select "Install" or "Try without installing", I got this error :

```
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)
```

I've seen on some other posts that I could try to update my BIOS. I did this, but didn't work. 
It also happens when I try to install Ubuntu, Kali or Fedora 27 on a virtual machine (host is Windows 10 professional, with VirtualBox). 
I guess it could be useful to give my CPU references, which are as follows :

> Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz, 2501 MHz, 4 core(s), 4 thread(s)

Thanks a lot !
Gaël

Comment: There is a bug report for this, at [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/+bug/1724650](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/+bug/1724650)  One of the suggestions for this was to use a version of microcode that the OP got from arch, and modify the liveUSB to use that microcode.

Comment: Thanks for your response !
Sadly, I'm kind of a beginner here, and I have no idea on how to modify the liveUSB, any clue ?
( I've seen some tutorials for Linux users, but I'm don't have it yet :/ )
Thank you very much,
Gaël